# Swift SFSafariViewController present show blank page

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

EDIT2 
here is a MWC containing 2 classes with only the SFSafariViewController for opening an url embedded. What I get on screen is a blank page
The files are also here  https://github.com/camillegallet/testSwiftSafariEmbeded

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

View controller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SafariServices


class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var KronosWebsite: WKWebView!


    override func loadView() {
        KronosWebsite = WKWebView()
        self.view = KronosWebsite
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        openGoogle()
    }


    func openGoogle(){
        let url2=URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let web = SFSafariViewController(url: url2!)
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            do{
                topController.present(web, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }catch let error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("ERROR \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've this old  function in a library

```
    public func authorizeSafariEmbedded(from controller: UIViewController, at url: URL) throws -> SFSafariViewController {
        safariViewDelegate = OAuth2SFViewControllerDelegate(authorizer: self)
        let web = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        web.title = oauth2.authConfig.ui.title
        web.delegate = safariViewDelegate as! OAuth2SFViewControllerDelegate
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), let barTint = oauth2.authConfig.ui.barTintColor {
            web.preferredBarTintColor = barTint
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), let tint = oauth2.authConfig.ui.controlTintColor {
            web.preferredControlTintColor = tint
        }
        web.modalPresentationStyle = oauth2.authConfig.ui.modalPresentationStyle

        willPresent(viewController: web, in: nil)
        controller.present(web, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return web
    }
```

I call this function with those lines

```
                let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
                if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                    while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                        topController = presentedViewController
                    }
                    do{
                        let web = try authorizer.authorizeSafariEmbedded(from: topController,at: url!)
                    }catch let error {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print("ERROR \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But I keep having a blank page, I've not  found a correct working solution on the web
I've also tested with
let url=URL(string: "http://www.google.com")

even this don't works

```
    public func authorizeSafariEmbedded(from controller: UIViewController, at url: URL) throws -> SFSafariViewController {
        let web = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        web.title = oauth2.authConfig.ui.title
        controller.present(web, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return web
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Here what I've done to make it works

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!)

    @IBOutlet weak var KronosWebsite: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        KronosWebsite = WKWebView()
        self.view = KronosWebsite
    }

    func addViewControllerAsChildViewController() {
        addChild(safariVC)
        self.view.addSubview(safariVC.view)
        safariVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.setUpConstraints()

    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          addViewControllerAsChildViewController()
      }


    func setUpConstraints() {
           self.safariVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           self.safariVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
           self.safariVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
           self.safariVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
           self.safariVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

       }



}
```